# Is there a function to extract image patches in PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Given a batch of images, I'd like to extract all possible image patches, similar to a convolution. In TensorFlow, we can use [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches) to achieve this. Is there an equivalent function in PyTorch?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use tensorflow rewrite pytorch torch.nn.functional.unfold function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523441/how-to-use-tensorflow-rewrite-pytorch-torch-nn-functional-unfold-function)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there might not be a direct way to achieve your goal.
But Tensor.unfold function might be a solution.
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-smaller-image-patches-3d/16837/2
This website might help you.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this code example will help to understand how to use `unfold`, inspired by [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-extract-smaller-image-patches-3d/16837/2) thread linked by @gasoon, but a bit more verbose:

```
batch_size, n_channels, n_rows, n_cols = 32, 3, 64, 64
kernel_h, kernel_w = 7, 9
step = 5

x = torch.arange(batch_size*n_channels*n_rows*n_cols).view(batch_size, n_channels, n_rows, n_cols)

# unfold(dimension, size, step)
windows = x.unfold(2, kernel_h, step).unfold(3, kernel_w, step).permute(2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5).reshape(-1, n_channels, kernel_h, kernel_w)
print(windows.shape)
# result: torch.Size([4608, 3, 7, 9]) = [n_windows, n_channels, krenel_h, kernel_w]
```

Answer (score 4):

Spent a bit of time looking into this as well and I found [this pytorch thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tf-extract-image-patches-in-pytorch/43837/7) that was useful for me with PyTorch dev [ptrblck](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/ptrblck) (bless this dude) giving an equivalent pytorch version of the tensorflow function.

I'll just repost the code (from user [FloCF](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/FloCF)) here for simplicity.

```
import math
import torch.nn.functional as F

def extract_image_patches(x, kernel, stride=1, dilation=1):
    # Do TF 'SAME' Padding
    b,c,h,w = x.shape
    h2 = math.ceil(h / stride)
    w2 = math.ceil(w / stride)
    pad_row = (h2 - 1) * stride + (kernel - 1) * dilation + 1 - h
    pad_col = (w2 - 1) * stride + (kernel - 1) * dilation + 1 - w
    x = F.pad(x, (pad_row//2, pad_row - pad_row//2, pad_col//2, pad_col - pad_col//2))
    
    # Extract patches
    patches = x.unfold(2, kernel, stride).unfold(3, kernel, stride)
    patches = patches.permute(0,4,5,1,2,3).contiguous()
    
    return patches.view(b,-1,patches.shape[-2], patches.shape[-1])
```

Give those guys a like on the PyTorch forum :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use kornia [extract_tensor_patches](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#kornia.contrib.extract_tensor_patches). Explore also the APIs to combine back the patches, if needed.