# How to replicate PyTorch's nn.functional.unfold function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to use tensorflow to rewrite the pytorch's `torch.nn.functional.unfold` function:

```
#input x:[16, 1, 50, 36]
x = torch.nn.functional.unfold(x, kernel_size=(5, 36), stride=3)
#output x:[16, 180, 16]
```

I tried to use the function `tf.extract_image_patches()`:

`x = tf.extract_image_patches(x,ksizes=[1, 1,5, 98],strides=[1, 1, 3, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],padding='VALID')`

The input `x.shape`:`[16,1,64,98]`

I get the output `x.shape`:`[16,1,20,490]`

Then I reshape the `X` to `[16,490,20]`, that was I expect.

But I get the error when I feed the data:

```
UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Only support ksizes across space.
[[Node:hcn/ExtractImagePatches = ExtractImagePatches[T=DT_FLOAT, ksizes=[1, 1, 5, 98], padding="VALID", rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], strides=[1, 1, 3, 1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](hcn/Reshape)]]
```

How could I use tensorflow to rewrite pytorch `torch.nn.functional.unfold` function to change the `X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [16, 50, 36, 1])
x = tf.extract_image_patches(x, ksizes=[1, 4, 98, 1], strides=[1, 4, 1, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
```